# Python converting string to float gives an error showing the number as mix of letter and number

Tags: python

I got an strange error I have never seen before and I tried to find some information over the web but without sucess.

I try to do a simple thing, converting an str to flaot. When I print the value it is in classic number style (37 442.20) but when I want to convert it to flaot I get an Error showing the value in a mix of number and letter (37\u202f442.20). With the following lines I get :

```
print(value)
print(type(value))

37 442.20
<class 'str'>

print(float(value))
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '37\u202f442.20'
```

Someone know what's going wrong here ?

Comment: That string has two numbers: `37` and `442.20`.  Which one are you trying to convert?  You can't convert them both at once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
s = "37 442.20"

print (float(s.replace(' ','').encode('ascii', 'ignore')))
```

Output:

```
37442.2
```

You have both the space and encoding problems.

So you use `replace()` method on your string and `encode()` to pass through each and print your `float`.

In order to avoid error upon conversion of a list of mixed non digit string and digit strings, and considering your encoding problem, you can do:

```
import re

sl = ["37 442.20","aaa.83","4a3.","aaaa","345"]

for s in sl:
    s = s.replace(' ','').encode('ascii', 'ignore')
    if re.match(b"^([0-9]+){0,1}[.]{0,1}([0-9]+)$",s):
        print (float(s))
    else:
        print ("%s not digit" % s.decode())
```

Output:

```
37442.2
aaa.83 not digit
4a3. not digit
aaaa not digit
345.0
```

Comment: okay the encoding was the issue !! s = s.replace(' ','').encode('ascii', 'ignore') worked ! Thx a lot !!

Comment: No problem! think about accepting my answer if that helped (click on the gray tick top left of it)

Answer (score 2):

It’s simply because you have white space between digits. Remove the white space and pass the value to `float` and it should work fine.

One way to do this:

```
value = “”.join(‘37 442.20’.split())
print(float(value))
```

Comment: Could you change the quotation marks so that the code works.

Comment: @Jolbas the quotes characters you use doesn’t affect the output.

Comment: I get `SyntaxError: invalid character '“' (U+201C)` if I copy and paste your code

Comment: @Jolbas You don’t need to copy-paste it. It’s a double quote. It’s on your standard keyboard. Shift+single quote.

Answer (score 0):

The `\u202f` character is not a normal space.
https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/202f/index.htm

You can try remove them first before converting. For example:
`u'37\u202f442.20'.encode('ascii', 'ignore')`